# Differences between ODI 11g and 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I want to see the main differences between the two versions of ODI:

1. 11g
2. 12c

From what I know, some of them are:

- 12c permits multiple target tables, while 11g NO;
- new objects to 12c (Reusable Mappings, Global Templates);
- 12c implements Wallet;

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When 12c was released I wrote two blogs explaining all the new features :

- [Part 1](https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2013/10/oracle-data-integrator-12c-release-part-1/)
- [Part 2](https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2013/11/oracle-data-integrator-12c-release-part-2/)

Since then, there are been improvements to connect to Big Data, SaaS Apps (Oracle ERP Cloud, Salesforce.com, ...), Oracle Autonomous Data Warehouse Cloud, Oracle Autonomous Transaction Processing Cloud, Oracle Object Storage, REST, ...

There are also new features to ease development lifecycle. With [Deployment Archives](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.3/odidg/release-management.html) you can easily promote ODI objects from one environment to another.

Answer (score 1):

Please see below differences between ODI 11g and 12c

1. Source and target data tables can now be dragged and dropped to the same canvas, which was not the case for the previous version.
2. all objects have IN and OUT connectors. There is also a possibility to use multiple targets within the same mapping as the OUT connector can be mapped to many IN connectors.
3. there are changes in Procedure GUI compare to 11G.  Here we can create options directly whereas in 11G We have to Right-click on Procedure and then we can create options.
4. Hive Technology Added for Hadoop.
5. Step-by-Step Debugger: It provides you options to set breakpoints, inspect the values of variables, debug sessions or data. Step by step, you can easily review your work.
6. Oracle Warehouse Builder Integration
7. More nice Features We also found in 12c which make our lives easier. One of them is the auto-completion and syntax highlighting in expression fields. Another one is that when one column is selected all the related columns are highlighted across the mapping.
8. a new components panel has been added in 12c, containing operations like join, filter, lookup or split to simplify mapping creation.